NSView equivalent to UIView's systemLayoutSizeFitting
How can I calculate the optimal size of a NSView based on its current constraints and a target size?
UIView provides:
func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
func systemLayoutSizeFitting( _ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize
What would the equivalent NSView code for calculating the size?
NSView's fittingSize only provides the minimum size of the view that satisfies the constraints it holds.

There is no direct equivalent ... if you describe your actual use-case, there may be a suitable approach.
